# Identify XML Serialization rule(s) specified in a class

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

### Is it possible to do the following :

**Create an instance of *SomeCLass* in another part of my code AND

Using *this* newly created instance/object can I obtain the :**

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("someClass")]
XML Serialization rule

**What I am Trying To Achieve :**
1. Identify whether *SomeCLass* contains an XML Serialization rule on any property in it
2. If it does contain such a serialization rule, ***identify the rule*.

    (i.e. whether its an ... XMLIgnore || XMLElement || XMLAttribute ... etc.)**

---

#### The class referred to in the question :

```
    Class SomeClass
    {
            SomeOtherClass[] privtArr;

            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("SomeOtherClass")]
            public SomeOtherClass[] anInstance
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.privtArr;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.privtArr = value;
                }
            } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create an instance; simply look at the `Type`, in particular `GetFields()` and `GetProperties()`. Loop over the public *non-static* fields/properties, and check `Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(member, attributeType)` - i.e.

```
public class Test
{
    [XmlElement("abc")]
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    static void Main()
    {
        var props = typeof (Test).GetProperties(
              BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach(var prop in props)
        {
            if(Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(XmlIgnoreAttribute)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ignore: " + prop.Name);
                continue; // it is ignored; stop there
            }
            var el = (XmlElementAttribute) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
                   prop, typeof (XmlElementAttribute));
            if(el != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Element: " + (
                  string.IsNullOrEmpty(el.ElementName) ?
                  prop.Name : el.ElementName));
            }
            // todo: repeat for other interesting attributes; XmlAttribute,
            // XmlArrayItem, XmlInclude, etc...
        }
    }
}
```

If you *do* need to create an instance, use `new` or `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Comment: **@Marc, thank you for the answer it was exactly what I had in mind.** Sorry about not responding earlier as I was still working on the code block where I implemented this & thought I would leave the question open in-case any other related doubts popped up.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to instantiate SomeClass.

use Reflection to list (public) fields and properties of `typeof(SomeClass)`.
Then for each field/property, enumerate attributes and filter the ones you are interested in (such as `XmlElement()`, `XmlAttribute()`,...

Note however that the `XmlSerializer` serializes public fields and properties even if they don't have an `XmlBlah` attribute. They are serialized unless they are marked as `[XmlIgnore()]`. You should then lookup this attribute as well.

Of course, you may also be interested in Xml attributes at the class level.

Comment: Thank you. The note helped, did not know/realize that public fields got serialized; As in all serializable classes I had created public  properties to access private fields.